# Creating an effective loop to gather data from an API for each item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to achieve is an effective way of passing each item found in a specific attribute through a JSON request in jQuery, so that I can gather information about it from an API. The API is Twitch and each data attribute is a streamers name.

Each streamer would be defined like so -

`<div streamer='streamer_name'></div>`

and from the API I'd like to gather their status and information. However, the Twitch API does not showcase information about offline streamers in the original API url, and so I have to use two API URL's to get all the required data.

I have created something that works, and as I'm rather new to this, I've most likely missed out on important features required to make this as effective as possible.

```js
$('[streamer]').each(function() {
  var data = $(this);
  var streamer = $(data).attr('streamer');
  $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + streamer, function(x) {
    if (x.stream != null) {
      $(data).append(
        //online data
      );
    } else {
      $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/' + streamer, function(x) {
        $(data).append(
          //offline data
        );
      });
    }
  })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/8801/ for an example of what this code actually does.

**EDIT:** There is also a way to search for multiple streamers at once, although again, it does not show any data for those that are offline.

https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?channel=riotgames,scrags

**EDIT2:** To be more specific about my doubts, occasionally it will append the data incorrectly and will break the page layout, or not show up at all. This happens quite frequently upon page refreshes.

Thanks

Comment: Is there an api to get multiple streamers at once? If not then this seems like a fine way to do it.

Comment: There is, although it does not allow you to gather data about offline streamers. https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?channel=riotgames,scrags

Comment: What part are you concerned about? General approach seems OK.

Comment: Frequently I'd have problems with the appended data not showing up after a page refresh, which would leave required data fields blank until it was refreshed again. I'm not 100% sure whether this was due to what I've got so far.